# control play pause button in fragment from musicplayer service

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

i create a musicplayer service class in android and have a play pause button in a fragment.
I am running a radio stream in musicplayer service.
The service is running on background.
When the app is open service can control by play pause button.
but when app is in background if i close the service play pause button sometime not changed. how can i solve that

```
public class RadioStreamFragment extends Fragment {
    //Constant
    private static final String TAG = "RadioStreamFragment";

    //Member variables
    private String mTitle = "";
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private boolean mIsPlaying = false;
    private int mMaxVolume;
    private int mVolume;
    private OnSeekBarChangeListener mListener;
    private AudioManager mAudioManager;

    //View member variables
    private TextView mTVTitle;
    //private ImageView mImageView;
    public static  Button mButton;
    private SeekBar mSeekBar;
    private AutoScrollViewPager pager;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_radio, null);

        //Init view
        initView(view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        if (mTitle != null)
            setTitleText(mTitle);
        if (mBitmap != null)
            setImageCover(mBitmap);

        //TODO
        //Create seekBar state
        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        mMaxVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        mSeekBar.setMax(mMaxVolume);
        mSeekBar.setProgress(mVolume);
        if (mListener != null)
            mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(mListener);
        else {
            mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(activity.mSeekBarListener);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Volume : " + mVolume + "/" + mMaxVolume);

        //Button state
        setButtonState(mIsPlaying);

        Log.d(TAG, "Resumed");
    }

    /* Property access functions
     * 
     */
    public void setTitleText(String title) {
        mTitle = MainActivity.Songtitle;
        mTVTitle.setText(MainActivity.Songtitle);
    }
    public void setImageCover(Bitmap bitmap) {
        mBitmap = bitmap;
    //  mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    public void setButtonState(boolean isPlaying) {
        mIsPlaying = isPlaying;
        final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (isPlaying) {
            if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                mButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_pause_radio));
            } else {
                mButton.setBackground(getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_pause_radio));
            }
        } else {
            if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                mButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_play_radio));
            } else {
                mButton.setBackground(getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_play_radio));
            }
        }
    }
    public void setMaxVolume(int value) {
        mMaxVolume = value;
    }
    public void setVolume(int value) {
        mVolume = value;
    }
    public void setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OnSeekBarChangeListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
    public int getMaxVolume() {
        return mMaxVolume;
    }
    public int getVolume() {
        return mVolume;
    }
    public SeekBar getVolumeSeekBar() {
        return mSeekBar;
    }
    public String getTitleText() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    /* Internal Functions
     * 
     */
    Button hbir;
    Button lb;
    private Handler handler;
    private void initView(View view) {
        final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        mTVTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
    //  mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.im_radio_image);
        mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_play);    
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                MainActivity.tryagain=false;
                doPlay(v);
            }
        });

        hbir = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.hbit);   
        hbir.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                hbir.setEnabled(false);
                lb.setEnabled(false);
                mButton.setEnabled(false);
                Data.Initialize();

                Data.Initializehbit();
                MainActivity.tryagain=false;
                try{MainActivity.stopRadio();

                MainActivity.playRadio();
                if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    mButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources()
                            .getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_pause_radio));
                } else {
                    mButton.setBackground(getResources()
                            .getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_pause_radio));
                }
                as=false;

                }
                catch(Exception e){}

                hbir.setEnabled(false);
                lb.setEnabled(true);
                mButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        lb = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.lbit); 
        lb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                hbir.setEnabled(false);
                lb.setEnabled(false);
                mButton.setEnabled(false);
                Data.Initialize();
                final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                MainActivity.tryagain=false;

                try{MainActivity.stopRadio();
                MainActivity.playRadio();
                if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    mButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources()
                            .getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_pause_radio));
                } else {
                    mButton.setBackground(getResources()
                            .getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_pause_radio));
                }
                as=false;
                }
                catch(Exception e){}

                hbir.setEnabled(true);
                lb.setEnabled(false);
                mButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
        mSeekBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.sb_volume);
        mTVTitle.setText(MainActivity.Songtitle);


    /*  String[] imageUrls = new String[Imageurl.newyearsvalues.size()];
        for(int i=0; i<Imageurl.newyearsvalues.size(); i++)
        {
            ModelWPCategory modelWPCategory = new ModelWPCategory();
            modelWPCategory = wpCategories.get(i);
        //  categoryNames[i]= Imageurl.newyearsvalues.get(i);
            Log.d("kd", ""+Imageurl.newyearsvalues.get(i));
            imageUrls[i] = Imageurl.newyearsvalues.get(i);;
        }
        //int pagerPosition = bundle.getInt(Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, 0);

        ImagePagerAdapter im = new ImagePagerAdapter(imageUrls);
        pager = (AutoScrollViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pagera);
        pager.setAdapter(im);
        pager.setCurrentItem(0);
        pager.startAutoScroll();

        pager.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.c, R.anim.fade_out);
        anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

        pager.startAnimation(anim);
        anim.start();*/
        /*   handler = new Handler();
           handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    int i = pager.getCurrentItem();
                    if(i>=(pager.getAdapter().getCount()-1))
                        i=0;
                    else
                        i++;
                    pager.setCurrentItem(i);
                    pager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            },5000);*/

    //  mTVTitle.setText("Radio Station");

    }
    public static boolean as=false;
    public void doPlay(View view) {
        final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (!mIsPlaying && view.getId() == R.id.btn_play) {
            MainActivity.playRadio();
            if(as){
            try{
            if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                view.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_play_radio));
            } else {
                view.setBackground(getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_play_radio));
            }
            }catch(Exception e)
            {}
            as=false;
            }
            else
            {as=true;
            try{
                if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    view.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources()
                                .getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_pause_radio));
                    } else {
                        view.setBackground(getResources()
                                .getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_pause_radio));
                    }
                }catch(Exception e)
                {}
            }
        } else  {
            MainActivity.stopRadio();
            if(as){
                try{
                if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    view.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources()
                            .getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_play_radio));
                } else {
                    view.setBackground(getResources()
                            .getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_play_radio));
                }
                }catch(Exception e)
                {}
                as=false;
                }
                else
                {as=true;
                try{
                    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        view.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources()
                                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_pause_radio));
                        } else {
                            view.setBackground(getResources()
                                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_pause_radio));
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e)
                    {}
                }
        }


    }

}
```

musicplayer service class

```
import java.io.IOException;


import com.spoledge.aacdecoder.MultiPlayer;
import com.spoledge.aacdecoder.PlayerCallback;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MusicPlayerService extends Service {
    //Constant
    public static final String NOTIFICATION = "com.vg.intent.notification.musicplayer";
    public static final String STATUS = "STATUS";
    public static final String STATUS_PLAYING = "Playing";
    public static final String STATUS_STOPPED = "Stopped";
    public static final String STATUS_BUFFERING = "Buffering";
    public static final String STATUS_SERVICE_STARTED = "ServiceStarted";

    public static final String PLAY_THIS_ONE = "PlayThisOne";

    //Member variables
    private static final String TAG = "MusicPlayerSevices";
    private StreamBinder mBinder;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private MultiPlayer mPlayer;
    private PlayerCallback mPlayerCallback;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private boolean mIsMP3Pause = false;

    //Radio state variables
    private String mRadioTitle;
    private boolean mIsPlaying = false;

    /* Service Lifecycle Event Handler
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Service#onCreate()
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mBinder = new StreamBinder();
        initMusicPlayer();
        super.onCreate();
        sendNotification(STATUS, STATUS_SERVICE_STARTED);
        mHandler = new Handler();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate complete");
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (mBinder == null)
            mBinder = new StreamBinder();
        if (mPlayer == null)
            initMusicPlayer();
        if (mMediaPlayer == null)
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        handlingRequest(intent);
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand complete");
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY; //START_NOT_STICKY still work
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }
    /* MusicPlayerSevice functions
     * 
     */
    public void playRadio(final String url) {
        if (mIsMP3Pause) {
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            mIsMP3Pause = false;
        } else {
            //TODO
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    final NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                    // Connectivity issue, we quit
                    if (networkInfo == null || networkInfo.getState() != NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return;
                    }

                    String newUrl = "";
                    if (url.contains(".m3u")) {
                        newUrl = ParserM3UToURL.parse(url);
                    } else {
                        newUrl = url;
                    }
                    final String finalUrl = newUrl;
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mIsPlaying = true;
                            if (finalUrl.endsWith(".mp3")) {
                                //TODO
                                //Create media player to play instead
                                Log.d(TAG, "Start media player");
                                mPlayer.stop();
                                try {
                                    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(finalUrl);
                                    mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                mMediaPlayer.start();
                                mIsMP3Pause = false;
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Start multi player");
                                mPlayer.playAsync(finalUrl);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            thread.start();
        }
    }
    public void stopRadio() {
        mIsPlaying = false;
        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Stop media player");
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Stop multi player");
            mPlayer.stop();
        }
    }
    public void pauseRadio() {
        mIsPlaying = false;
        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Pause media player");
            mIsMP3Pause = true;
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Stop multi player");
            mPlayer.stop();
        }
    }
    public String getRadioTitle() {
        return mRadioTitle;
    }
    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return mIsPlaying;
    }

    //Internal function
    private void initMusicPlayer() {
        if (mPlayer == null) {
            mPlayerCallback = new PlayerCallback() {    



                @Override
                public void playerStopped(int perf) {
                    sendNotification(STATUS, STATUS_STOPPED);
                }

                @Override
                public void playerStarted() {
                    sendNotification(STATUS, STATUS_PLAYING);
                }

                @Override
                public void playerPCMFeedBuffer(boolean isPlaying, int bufSizeMs, int bufCapacityMs) {
                    if (!isPlaying) {
                        sendNotification(STATUS, STATUS_BUFFERING);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void playerMetadata(String key, String value) {
                    if (key != null && key.equals("StreamTitle")) {
                        mRadioTitle = Utils.stripHtml(value);
                        sendNotification(STATUS, mRadioTitle);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void playerException(Throwable throwable) {
                    final Throwable finalThrow = throwable;
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            stopRadio();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), finalThrow.getMessage()
                                    , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            sendNotification(STATUS, STATUS_STOPPED);
                        }
                    });
                }           
                @Override
                public void playerAudioTrackCreated(AudioTrack arg0) {}
            };
            //Workaround
            try {
                java.net.URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory( new java.net.URLStreamHandlerFactory(){
                    public java.net.URLStreamHandler createURLStreamHandler( String protocol ) {
                        Log.d( TAG, "Asking for stream handler for protocol: '" + protocol + "'" );
                        if ("icy".equals( protocol )) return new com.spoledge.aacdecoder.IcyURLStreamHandler();
                        return null;
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.w( TAG, "Cannot set the ICY URLStreamHandler - maybe already set ? - " + t );
            }
            mPlayer = new MultiPlayer(mPlayerCallback);
        }
    }
    private void handlingRequest(Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            String url = bundle.getString(PLAY_THIS_ONE);
            if (url != null) {
                playRadio(url);
                Log.d(TAG, "Receive playing request : " + url);
            }
            else {
                stopRadio();
                Log.d(TAG, "Receive stop request");
            }
        }
    }
    private void sendNotification(String key, String value) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(NOTIFICATION);
        intent.putExtra(key, value);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    // Nested class
    public class StreamBinder extends Binder {
        public MusicPlayerService getService() {
            return MusicPlayerService.this;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Communication from a fragment / activity to a service is exactly like passing data from activity to activity.**

Put your data (maybe an int that means pause to your app) into an intent and start the service with that intent.  The onStartCommand will fire and your service pulls the data int out of the intent realizes it is a pause command and pauses.

*Communication from a service to an app well that's where it get's tricky.  There are too many methods to cover in a single answer.*

Answer (score 1):

You have to think in your player service as if it was an automaton. At any moment, it might be in any state X for example state.Playing , state.Pause... Whenever you recreate your view when the user comes back to the app (either via fragment or activity) you have to request the media player to give you the current state and paint your interface buttons according to it. Thus, send an intent to your service everytime the fragment or the activity gets recreated asking for its state. The service should call a method like `getState()`. Then, broadcast from the service and intent with its state, for instance `state.STOP`. In your fragment/activity there must be a BroadcastReceiver registered hearing for this intents, so that, when the state intent is received you update your buttons accordingly, and that's all :)